# Retrieve the user requests from a website using a desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had made a site for client in which users can make request for songs, there's a database having songname, by whom, written by, sang at etc. The site is hosted and working fine.

The way the admin gets to know what is asked for is by using the website but now he wants that there be a desktop application which displays all the requests so he does not have to log in and use the website

I do have an idea to get this done, but I am hoping for a well known established way. I am using C# asp.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create an [Http Handler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001). This handler will listen to the request and you can log them in a database, and the windows application will read from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Timer in windows application.

Set your Timer to either 1 min or 2 min as per your need.and on its Tick event you check the live database whether is there any new request come or not..

If new request come then you can show some notification or something like this...